# CentOs 7 CronTab set JAVA_HOME

Tags: centos, cron, environment-variables, java

With the `root` user I configured the JAVA_HOME variable for crontab like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# vim /etc/crontab
_______
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_71/bin
MAILTO=root
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_71
_______
```

I have defined a cronjob run by a different user named `tomcat` like this:

```
[tomcat@localhost ~]$ crontab -e
_______
30 10 * * * /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh >> /opt/tomcat/logs/cron_restart.log 2>&1
32 10 * * * /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh >> /opt/tomcat/logs/cron_restart.log 2>&1
_______
```

The job runs, but my log says the following:

```
[tomcat@localhost ~]$ vim /opt/tomcat/logs/cron_restart.log
______
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
______
```

**1.) Why is the crontab not picking up the JAVA_HOME?

2.) Which possibilities are there to tell crontab where the JAVA_HOME is?**

My approach is based on the CentOs-Docs from this page:
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-autotasks-cron-configuring.html

**3.) Is it possible that i misread the docs?**

Comment: Just making sure : you are aware that you're reading docs for CentOS 5, correct? There might be differences.

Comment: Please  do not edit for the answer, answer to your own question, and select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working this way:

Insert the following line in the file `/opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh`:
`export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_71"`